# GetFileAttributes with environment variables

Tags: visual-c++, file-attributes

I am trying to have a file exist or not in a path using vc++.

```
if (INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES != GetFileAttributes(L"%windir%\Myfile.exe"))
        printf("\n %ws", sPath);
```

I've put Myfile.exe in windows directory. Still it is not giving me right output.

Please help me.

Comment: You must expand environment variables yourself.  Like the vast majority of winapi functions, GetFileAttributes() does not do it for you.  Use the one that does, GetEnvironmentVariable().

Comment: @HansPassant LPWSTR sExPath = new TCHAR[1024];GetEnvironmentVariable(L"%windir%\MyFile.exe", sExPath, sizeof(sExPath) / sizeof(*sExPath));
  printf("\n %ws", sExPath); returns garbadge value

Comment: Only pass L"windir".  And ever ignore a winapi return value, you at a minimum want to assert() it so you can diagnose simple failure.

Comment: You are looking for `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` - it behaves the way you erroneously expect `GetEnvironmentVariable` to behave.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that

```
CString GetEnvironmentVarValue(CString strEnvVarName)
{
    TCHAR szVarValue[MAX_PATH] = "" ;
    GetEnvironmentVariable(strEnvVarName.GetBuffer(0), szVarValue, sizeof(szVarValue)) ;
    GetLongPathName(szVarValue, szVarValue, sizeof(szVarValue)) ;
    return CString(szVarValue) ;
}
```